# Unable to understand position property of css

Tags: html, css

If `<p>` tag position is absolute then `div` comes in a row but after commenting position absolute then `div` comes downward even if `position:relative`. Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-content {
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #be6180, #973f5c, #64293d);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 25px;
}

.card-content {
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #f3c83b, #dfa72e, #e24428);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

p {
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="card-content"><p>This is my page</p></div>
      <div class="card-content"><p>This is my page</p></div>
      <div class="card-content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is used inline-block divs without `vertical-align` property, not in `p` tag's absolute. You can fix this by adding `vertical-align: top` to `.card-content` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the elements, you can use `vertical-align`.

> The following values are possible to fix your Problem:
> `vertical-align: middle;`, `vertical-align: bottom;`, `vertical-align: top;`, `vertical-align: text-bottom;`, `vertical-align: text-top;`,

Here's the code (I added `vertical-align: middle` to your `card-content`):

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-content {
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #be6180, #973f5c, #64293d);
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 25px;
}

.card-content {
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, #f3c83b, #dfa72e, #e24428);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle; /* Also possible: Bottom, top, text-bottom and text-top */
}

p {
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="card-content"><p>This is my page</p></div>
      <div class="card-content"><p>This is my page</p></div>
      <div class="card-content"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @GucciBananaKing99 you have fixed my problem

Comment: @NiteshSaini I am glad that I could help. But please note to mark the question with a check mark to show other users that it was a helpful answer.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow so, I don't know how and where to mark the question for others but, I would never do that again. Thanks for advice @GucciBananaKing99